# Why is DialogFragment causing ClassCastExcepetion?

Tags: android, android-fragments, callback, android-dialogfragment

I have a ViewPager fragment instantiating a DialogFragment. Because the Android Developer guide says...

> "All Fragment-to-Fragment communication is done through the associated
>   Activity. Two Fragments should never communicate directly."

... this DialogFragment provides a callback to MainActivity, which then feeds that information down to the ViewPager fragment.

My DialogFragment "ModeDialogFragment" calls the following method from within onClick:

```
((MainActivity)getActivity()).updateData();
```

The updateData method in MainActivity identifies the ViewPager fragment 'MyFragment' and starts a method doUpdateData().

```
public void updateData(){
        // Call function that generates the correct tab to identify MyFragment
        MyFragment myFrag = (MyFragment) findFragmentByPosition(3); // Exception occurs here
        myFrag.doUpdateData();
        }

public Fragment findFragmentByPosition(int position) {
        int viewId = R.id.pager
        return getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(
                makeFragmentName(viewId, position));
    }

String makeFragmentName(int viewId, int position)
    {
         return "android:switcher:" + viewId + ":" + position;
    }
```

However, when I run the code, I get the following ClassCastException:

```
07-13 01:19:53.972: E/AndroidRuntime(1660): java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.myapp.ModeDialogFragment cannot be cast to com.example.myapp.MyFragment
```

(I can provide the rest if asked.) I understand they can't be cast as the same if they are quite different, but why is ModeDialogFragment interfering at all? findFragmentByPosition() is not returning a ModeDialogFragment, I don't see why MainActivity should complain. The only connection is that ModeDialogFragment is performing the call. I am rather new to this, so is it possible that I am I doing my callback incorrectly?

**EDIT:** Some extra code.
This is my ViewPagerAdapter:

```
public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) {
        switch (index) {
        case 0:
            // Fragment0 tab
            return new Fragment0();
        case 1:
            // Fragment1 tab
            return new Fragment1();
        case 2:
            // Fragment2 tab
            return new Fragment2();
        case 3:
            // MyFragment tab
            return new MyFragment();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // get item count - equal to number of tabs
        return 4;
    }

}
```

This is how I am starting my ModeDialogFragment, extending Fragment, from clicking a ListView item:

```
    myList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parentAdapter, View view, int position, long id)
        {
            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

            ModeDialogFragment modeDialog = ModeDialogFragment.newInstance(R.string.mode_calibration);
            String title = makeFragmentName(R.id.pager, 3); // As in MainActivity. Takes ViewPager ID and fragment number.
            //ft.add(modeDialog, title);
            modeDialog.show(ft, title);
        }
    }
```

Comment: *I have a ViewPager fragment instantiating a DialogFragment.* - is the `ModeDialogFragment` used as a page in the `ViewPager` or you just start it from one of the pages(as a side note `ViewPager` starts the page count from `0`)? I've seen that you marked the line with the exception, are you sure it happens there(just to be absolutely sure)? Also, please don't prefix your questions titles with tag names as android, the tags at the bottom are more than enough to show the scope of the question.

Comment: (I'll keep that in mind about the tags, I didn't know that. Thanks.) The DialogFragment is not a page, itself, it is just meant to appear over the top and starting from page #4 (so count of 3). I am certain that is the line at which the exception occurs - at least, it is the line specified by the LogCat.

Comment: Can you post the code for the pager's adapter?

Comment: The code for the adapter itself, or the instantiation of the dialog from within the pager's fragment?

Comment: Post both to see what you're doing.

Comment: I am not sure if you are notified for it, but I have now edited the question. I will take another look through the full ModeDialogFragment code to see if it is worth posting.

Comment: The dialog fragment is added with a tag using `makeFragmentName(R.id.pager, 3)`, which is the same tag you use later to retrieve the `MyFragment`. So you end up with two fragments with the same tag and apparently the `FragmentManager` gets the dialog fragment first when using the tag. Change the tag that you use with the `ModeDialogFragment` to something else(like "mode_dialog").

Comment: I just had that realisation now when playing around with that makeFragmentName values - 0, 1 and 2 connected to the correct fragments but 3 connected to the ModeDialogFragment. It was overwriting MyFragment. The code now runs straight through, no problems. Thanks! I'll type up the proper answer to this code soon, unless you'd like to do the honours yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code you posted it seems you are using the same tag for both the fragments that are involved. `ModeDialogFragment` is added using `makeFragmentName(R.id.pager, 3)` which is the same tag that the `ViewPager` uses for `MyFragment`, so when the `FragmentManager`  tries to retrieve the fragment using the tag you get the wrong one.

The solution is to change the tag that you use when showing the `ModeDialogFragment`.